How to redirect an unauthorized user to a contact page in PowerApps
I have a PowerApps canvas app. I have a requirement from client that if an user is trying to access the app with whom the app is not shared, in that case the user should be redirected to a page where we will display a contact email to contact for access.
Please guide me on above requirement.
